# Avoid duplication in doctor_id field with where clause in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent, duplicates, unique

this is my doctors id

[image]

this is my user id

[image]

[image]I can't insert anything when I put `unique` in the validation of `doctor_id`. When there's no `unique` it works fine.

I want to avoid duplicate `doctor_id` where `auth::id == 1`. Any advice is appreciated.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{    
     $auth = Auth::id();
     $constraints = [
        'doctor_id' => 'required|unique',
        'day1' => 'required|max:20',
        'day2'=> 'required|max:60',
        'day3' => 'required|max:60'
        ];
    $input = [
        'users_id' => $auth,
        'doctor_id' => $id,
        'day1' => $request['day1'],
        'day2' => $request['day2'],
        'day3' => $request['day3'],
        'day4' => $request['day4'],
         ...
        'day27' => $request['day27'],
        'status' => '1'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $constraints);
    Itinerary::create($input);
    $added = array('added'=> 'Added Doctor to Itinerary Successful!!');
    return redirect()->back()->with($added);
```

Comment: Can you show us all the related table structures?

Comment: hi i picture of my table

Comment: I need to see **all** the related tables e.g. `users`, `doctors` etc.

Comment: hi @Fahmi i add users and doctors table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? (assuming your table is named `itineraries`):

```
'doctor_id' => 'unique:itineraries'
```

According to Laravel Doc, you should add the table name, and column name if possible:

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

Comment: hi i'd try you suggestion that work the problem is it keeps on inserting and it duplicated the doctor_id. i want doctor id unique when it will duplicate it will have an error

Comment: @SebastianMendoza can you show me the structure of the itineraries table? Any errors?

Comment: Also, what does the $id field hold? It seems to me $id and $auth are not so clear. It would be good if you use clearer variable names. Please provide more info about your model and controllers.

Comment: $auth = Auth::id(); - it is the user id, $id = url id the id of the doctor i have to input

Comment: i dont want to duplicate the doctor_id.

Comment: @SebastianMendoza Thanks for adding more information. I don't understand clearly the relations /purpose of your application. It would be good if you explain more clearly.

Comment: @SebastianMendoza You should also add this to your migration of "itineraries" table: `$table->string('doctor_id')->unique();` With this, you won't have duplicate `doctor_id`s but you will get an error with your current controller. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes Without more information it's difficult to help.. sorry

Comment: hi sir @john i add additional info